# How do I get the keypath for a nested property in an object?

Tags: javascript, recursion, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using `Firebase`, and their `update` function allows for multi-location updates using the following syntax:

```
newData['users/abc/age'] = 23
newData['users/xyz/hair'] = 'blue'
firebase.database().ref().update(newData)
```

I'm working on a utility function that will flatten deeply nested objects into an object like `newData`. This involves recursively iterating through the object and keeping track of the keys as the loop descends.

So far, I have this (it's just adding the path tiers to an array now. once the algo is correct, i'll simply use `.join('/')`):

```
function getKeypaths(obj, paths = []) {

    let keys = Object.keys(obj)

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let propName = keys[i]

        paths.push(propName)
        if (typeof obj[propName] === "object" && typeof obj[propName] !== null) {
            console.log("PUSHING PATH", propName, paths)
            getKeypaths(obj[propName], paths)
        } else {
            console.log("val", obj[propName], paths)

        }
    }
}


let obj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: {
                d: 1
            }
        },
        x: {
            y: {
                z: 2
            }
        }
    }
}

getKeypaths(obj)
```

When I run this, the `console.log` output looks like this:

```
PUSHING PATH a [ 'a' ]
PUSHING PATH b [ 'a', 'b' ]
PUSHING PATH c [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
val 1 [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
PUSHING PATH x [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x' ]
PUSHING PATH y [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y' ]
val 2 [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
```

As you can see, the loop is retaining the path of the previous value when it starts digging for the next non-object value. the last line of the output should read: `val 2 [ 'a', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]`

I then tried to clear the `path` array once the loop returned to a previous level:

```
function getKeypaths(obj, paths = []) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj)
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let propName = keys[i]
        if (propName) paths.push(propName)
        if (typeof obj[propName] === "object" && typeof obj[propName] !== null) {
            console.log("PUSHING PATH", propName, paths)
            getKeypaths(obj[propName], paths)
            paths.length = 0
        } else {
            console.log("val", obj[propName], paths)
        }
    }
}

getKeypaths(obj)
```

But that only resulted in the loop forgetting the `path` prior to its current level after the first `value`:

```
PUSHING PATH a [ 'a' ]
PUSHING PATH b [ 'a', 'b' ]
PUSHING PATH c [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
val 1 [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
PUSHING PATH x [ 'x' ]
PUSHING PATH y [ 'x', 'y' ]
val 2 [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
```

Any suggestions? Open to helper libraries if there's a more straightforward way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`json-pointer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-pointer) to do what you want.

That module includes a [`dict`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-pointer#dictobject) function that returns an object containing JSON pointer keys and their associated values. For example:

```
var jsonPointer = require("json-pointer");

var data = {
    users: {
        abc: {
            age: 23
        },
        xyz: {
            hair: "blue"
        }
    }
};
var dict = jsonPointer.dict(data);
```

The resultant dictionary will be:

```
{
    "/users/abc/age": 23,
    "/users/xyz/hair": "blue"
}
```

The keys/paths will start with a slash, but Firebase will still treat them as relative to the ref upon which `update` is called.

Comment: a superb solution, works perfect.  if anyone needs this for a similar purpose, note that: **(a)** arrays are spread into `objs` keyed on `index`, ie `jsonPointer.dict(['a', 'b', 'c']) == {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}` (which is what Firebase will do with them anyway), and **(b)** it will add `null`s and `undefined`s to the resultant `object`--I just added a simple loop to remove those values before pushing to firebase, [snippet is here](https://runkit.com/brandonmp/583c60989f00610014775b5f)

Answer (score 0):

[ I've got a working method, but I'm not going to `accept` this answer in hopes that someone w/ more expertise here can opine/correct me if I'm wrong ]

After changing the variable where I store the `path` from an `array` to a `string`, as well as some other changes to the algo in the OP, this solution seems to work so far:

```
export const flattenForUpdate = (obj, path = '') => {
  var newData = {}

  const _flatten = (_obj, _path) => {
    try {
        for (var propName in _obj) {
            if (_obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
                if (typeof _obj[propName] === "object" 
                  && typeof _obj[propName] !== null
                  && Array.isArray(_obj[propName]) === false) {
                    _flatten(_obj[propName], _path + "/" + String(propName))
                } else if (_obj[propName] == null) {
                    throw new Error("Null/Undefined in Firebase data update payload!")
                } else {
                    let thisPath = _path + "/" + String(propName)
                    newData[thisPath] = _obj[propName]
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("ERROR IN FLATTENING", err)
    }
  }
  _flatten(obj, path)
  return newData

 }
```

It's a bit messy but the key takeaways are:

- it will return `Arrays` just like it will a `primitive`, b/c `arrays` in firebase are weird and can't really support atomic granular updates, so simplest case is to overwrite current array in firebase
- it will throw on `null` as well as `undefined`. `undefined` in an `update()` payload will cause an error that prevents the entire write, and `null` will **delete** whatever value was there, which is presumably not desirable
- it is a closures (i think). I have never used `closures` before afaik, but to my understanding, because it's recursive, any internal state has to be held in a different `context` than the function doing the actual recursion--which evidently is why God/ECMA/Douglas Crockford or whoever made JS included JS.